# Taylor coefficients of the function $x^{1/x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion, recursion

I'm interested in the following function:

$$\begin{aligned}
f(x)&=x^{\frac{1}{x}}\\
&=e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln x}\end{aligned}
$$

I'd like to find its Taylor coefficients (specifically around the point at $x=1$), because they form an interesting progression numerically that I can't quite find a pattern to.

I've been able to find the first few derivatives, but they don't seem to form a useful pattern.

$$
\mathrm{define} \ f_1(x)\equiv1-\ln x$$
$$\begin{align}f'(x)&=\frac{1}{x^2}f_1(x)f(x)\\
f''(x)&=\frac{1}{x^3}\left(\frac{1}{x}f_1(x)^2-2 f_1(x)-1\right)f(x)\end{align}
$$

While this is *sort of* a recursive formula, it's just getting more complicated and doesn't seem particularly useful. It's clear that it will always be some function multiplied by $f(x)$, but what that function is for each derivative isn't clear. What are some strategies for finding Taylor coefficients in general, and for this function in particular? I'd like to find an expression in terms of a sum or something, or at least a recursion relation.

Note that I suspect (but have not proven) that this function is smooth but non-analytic at the origin, considering its relation to the famous function $e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$. I don't know if that's relevant in terms of how difficult its Taylor series is to find.

Comment: You might look at [OEIS sequence A008405](https://oeis.org/A008405).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, for $|x|<1$, \begin{align*}
f(x) &= \exp\! \bigg( {\frac{{\log (1 + (x - 1))}}{{1 + (x - 1)}}} \bigg) = \exp\! \bigg( {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\bigg( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{( - 1)^{k + 1} }}{k}( - 1)^{n - k} } } \bigg)(x - 1)^n } } \bigg) \\ & = \exp\! \bigg( {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^{n + 1} H_n (x - 1)^n } } \bigg)
 = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {B_n (1, \ldots ,( - 1)^{n + 1} n!H_n )\frac{{(x - 1)^n }}{{n!}}} ,
\end{align*}
where $H_n$ are the [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and $B_n$ are the [complete exponential Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Exponential_Bell_polynomials).

Alternatively, if we set
$$
\exp\! \bigg( {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^{n + 1} H_n (x - 1)^n } } \bigg) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {a_n (x - 1)^n } 
$$
then $a_0=1$ and
$$
a_n  = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {( - 1)^{k + 1} kH_k a_{n - k} } 
$$
for $n\ge 1$. The OEIS entry [$\text{A}008405$](https://oeis.org/A008405) provides the following formula in terms of the [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind):
$$
a_n  = \frac{1}{n!}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {s(n,k)\sum\limits_{j = 0}^k {( - j)^{k - j} \binom{k}{j}} } .
$$

Comment: Ah! This is much nicer than the series I was working on over the past few days -- I expanded it by brute force, and ended up with a sum over multinomials. This is a much more elegant solution, and I especially appreciate the reference to a sum formula of the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Since Taylor series of $e^x$ is uniformly convergent we have that Taylor series of $e^{\log(x)/x} = \sum_i \frac{\log(x)^i}{x^i i !}$

Now apply the Taylor series of $\log(x)$ around $1$ in the above series and you get the Taylor series of $x^{1/x}$ around $x=1$.

Or the coefficients can be obtained from using the formula in
[Understanding an aplication of Faà di Bruno's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2683638/understanding-an-aplication-of-fa%c3%a0-di-brunos-formula)

Comment: Is it possible that is should be $(\log(x)/x)^i$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I presume that the factor of $1/x^i$ cancels out the ordinary $x^i$ term in a Taylor series

Comment: @a52 That is incorrect. We are essentially using $$ e^y = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{y^i}{i!}$$ and setting $y=\log(x)/x$.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I corrected the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Balajisb Your approach is not that easy. One would have to resum the correct terms (as you will get the power series of $\log(x)$ to the power $i$ and then one needs to isolate the correct terms).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2683638/understanding-an-aplication-of-fa%c3%a0-di-brunos-formula I have added this link in my answer also.